# vb.net insert Checkbox value to the MS server database

Tags: vb.net

i want to insert checkbox value to MS server database but not work, show some error" Operator '&' is not defined for string and checkbox"

here is my code and database table name "test" column name "chk"  , any body can give me advise? thanks!

```html
Protected Sub chk(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chk.CheckedChanged

 Dim connectionString As String = "data source=xxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;User Id=xxx;Password=xxx;Integrated Security=SSPI"
    Using cn2 As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand
        If cbxIsCloud.Checked = True Then
            cmd2 = New SqlCommand("Insert into test (chk) VALUES (chk)", cn2)
            cn2.Open()
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cn2.Close()

        End If
    End Using
```

```html
 <td>
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="uamCheckBox" Width="10px" />
</td>
```

Comment: First thing to do would be to use parameters.  While there are security benefits really the best part is it makes your whole constructing sql statements much simpler, maintainable and reliable

Comment: thanks Hursey, so it should change "INSERT INTO test (chk) VALUES(@chk)" and use Parameters.AddWithValue? thanks

Comment: AddWithValue should be used with caution,  can result in some unexpected type conversion.  Better to add parameters and set types explicitly

Comment: thanks Hursey . but database no any record when i click the button.do you have any idea? thanks

Comment: What’s the result of execute non query?

Comment: i updated my code and run the program show  "cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()", Invalid column name .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your still a little off on the whole parameter thing, something like this is where I think you need to be heading

```
Protected Sub chk(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chk.CheckedChanged

 Dim connectionString As String = "data source=xxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;User Id=xxx;Password=xxx;Integrated Security=SSPI"
    Using cn2 As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand
        If cbxIsCloud.Checked = True Then
            cmd2 = New SqlCommand("Insert into test (chk) VALUES (@chk)", cn2)
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@chk", SqlDbSqlDbType.Bit).Value = chk.Value
            cn2.Open()
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cn2.Close()

        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

You will notice here, I'm specifically typing the parameter, and I'm looking at the checkbox control value.  Your sample above, you are trying to save the checkbox itself to the DB which will either not work or give undesired results

One thing to watch out for, I'm not 100% sure about the DataType of Test.Chk in you DB.  I've assumed it's a boolean here, but I recall from your original question it looked like you where saving a string value